# How to fix Zen theme only showing correct breadcrumbs with theme developer module enabled?

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs, theming

I've been going around in circles with trying to get breadcrumbs working as the client wants them on a Drupal 7 site with a custom [Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen) theme working. I've built the site out and it requires the titles being added to the breadcrumb trail.

The issue is, the crumbs only display correctly with the theme developer module enabled. I know you can set the Zen theme's settings to append content titles to the breadcrumb trail, but this doesn't seem to work (either through specifying through the UI, or by changing the settings in the `MYTHEME.info` file). They do however correctly display with the `theme developer` module enabled. For a host of reasons I can't have a live site with this module enabled.

So,

- 1) How do I get the breadcrumbs working properly and why doesn't it work through the UI or in code?
- 2) How can I resolve this apparent conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, apparently there is a conflict between the Path Breadcrumb module and zen's built in breadcrumbs. When the Path Breadcrumb module is enabled, the zen breadcrumb doesn't append the title to the path. I'm assuming that Path Breadcrumb hooks into and overrides the drupal_get_breadcrumb(), although I haven't been able to demonstrate this myself. When I disable Path Breadcrumb, the zen breadcrumbs behave normally. This leaves me with two viable options: 1) hack the current status of the theme breadcrumbs, 2) or code Path Breadcrumbs for the rest of my pages. Neither options seems particularly palatable.

Comment: What kind of conflict? And is there any solution for it?

Comment: Hi Pierre, it looks like PB overrides the Zen theme...no solution, just possible workarounds. :(

Comment: Not sure how good your French is, but reading your edited version of your answer I'd just say ***Voilà!*** ... this is an interesting answer (see the "***à***" in it? I even have a French chars keyboard ...). PS: instead of posting my prior comment, another option that was suggested to me (in the review queue) was ... "**delete**" ... gggggggrrrrrrrrrr ... It's so easy to hit such delete option, instead of suggesting an appropriate (I hope) edit.

Comment: Je lis pas mal et Je parle en peut aussi...but I will always have to say "pardon" my French. So, Pierre, I guess you agree with my assessment, and it's time to dive into the zen breadcrumbs function...because I think it will be harder to code views page breadcrumbs. Merde.

Comment: Interesting additional comment ... and your French is not sooooo bad. Especially the last word, aka expression (watch out you don't get banned because of that ... hihihi). Apart from that: **Bonne chance** with your diving (can't help on that, sorry).

Comment: I just hope there aren't easily offensible french mods on Drupal answers